# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command

Tags: opencv, dll, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I'm following the instructions given by [Gilbert Tanner for Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/TannerGilbert/Tensorflow-Object-Detection-API-Train-Model). The following error comes up when running the command "python model_main_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_efficientdet_d0_512x512_coco17_tpu-8.config --model_dir=training --alsologtostderr":

```
2021-03-18 15:31:32.125194: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module> 
from object_detection import model_lib_v2
File ".\Anaconda3\envs\tf_2.3.0\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
from object_detection import eval_util
File ".\Anaconda3\envs\tf_2.3.0\lib\site-packages\object_detection\eval_util.py", line 36, in <module>
from object_detection.metrics import lvis_evaluation
File ".\Anaconda3\envs\tf_2.3.0\lib\site-packages\object_detection\metrics\lvis_evaluation.py", line 23, in <module>
from lvis import results as lvis_results
File ".\Anaconda3\envs\tf_2.3.0\lib\site-packages\lvis-0.5.3-py3.8.egg\lvis\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from lvis.vis import LVISVis
File ".\Anaconda3\envs\tf_2.3.0\lib\site-packages\lvis-0.5.3-py3.8.egg\lvis\vis.py", line 1, in <module>
import cv2
File ".\Anaconda3\envs\tf_2.3.0\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.
```

I have 16GB RAM (Intel Core i7-10510U CPU 1.80GHz 2.30GHz) and 8GB GPU memory (NVIDIA Quadro P520) and also tried to cleanup my disk and other instructions given in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLs10aNYths&t=1s).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What are your `python`, `openCV` and `tensorflow` versions?

Comment: Python version: 3.8.0, Tensorflow version: 2.4.1, Keras version: 2.3.1

Comment: Did you try reducing the batch size in the pipeline.config file?

Comment: Yes, even set the batch size to minimum possible (i.e, 1). But still getting the same error. I was thinking if it is about the memory limit Python uses. I use the 64-bit which should not be a problem

Comment: What is the OpenCV version?

Did the test command work (run from the research directory) successfully without any errors `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py`

Comment: pip show opencv-contrib-python
>>>4.5.1.48

Yes, it run successfully